# Is it possible to set default property to components in ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a simple component that looks like this:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/Gd-text-input">
    <label {{bind-attr for="name"}}>                 
      {{label}}
    </label>
    <input type="text"  {{bind-attr name="key" id="name"}} />
  </script>
```

I would like to add the attribute type to the input field, and if no type is passed when including the component, like this for example:

```
  {{Gd-text-input label="First Name" name="firstname" key="entry.810220554" }}
```

I would like it to default to type="text". How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6):

Yep, you can subclass `Ember.Component`:

```
YourApp.GdTextInputComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    type: 'text'
});
```